# Performance external GPIO interrupt on Orange Pi Zero

Tags: python, interrupt, gpio, orange-pi

I am using OPi.GPIO to detect one interrupt from my peripheral module. It worked fine with the low trigger but it was missing some signals at a higher frequency (It was latency). I jumped into the source code of the library, it seemed to handle the interrupt with using polling output logic level, not true interrupt same as the microcontroller.
I want to ask whether orange pi is possible to make a true interrupt.
I looked for the internet and found some libraries in python better than OPi.GPIO such as: wiring-pi, pigpio...

1. The wiring-pi was implemented by C language but I am using python
2. The pigpio seem to support only for Raspberry Pi but I am using Orange Pi

Which the best way should I do now to implement my project? I think about some ideas to resolve it below:

- Build the new hardware include microcontroller and the peripheral. I'll use the mcu to handle it and making one connection between this board and Orange Pi through some basic interfaces such as SPI, I2C or UART.
- Switch to Raspberry and use pigpio. I don't ensure whether the performance better than OPi.gpio
- Is it possible to build another library by myself? If yes, how can I build it?

I hope to get best suggestion. Many thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't rely on user space to handle GPIO interrupts. It has to be done on the kernel level as a proper driver.

Comment: Thanks, I am finding a way to build it on the kernel level

Comment: @ChinhNguyenHuu I'm having the same issue. Did you create/find a kernel level driver? Or how did you fix the issue?

Comment: @John Yes, I was using the kernel level to build a true interrupt pin. You can refer to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/driver-api/gpio.html
and the key value is gpio_request